# Common function in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am puzzled by the following question: if there is a common code for all controllers, for example, method of concrete controller, that detects available language for model requests:

```
public function language(Request $request) 
{
    $languages = ["en", "it"];
    $default = "en";

    return in_array($request->language, $languages) ? $request->language : $default;
}
```

So, some controllers contain this method, that I consider is amiss:

`Model::where("Lang", this.language())->get();`

Where to pull out this method `language()` avoiding duplication of code in each controller? Should it be injected service or simple static class helper?

Comment: I would do this by creating a helper file in your App directory, this is where I put repetitive functions and call them from there. Here is a really helpful guide: https://tutsforweb.com/creating-helpers-laravel/

Comment: Is it right to mess language business logic with others short functions?

Comment: I would put the language function in a helper file so you don't have to keep duplicating the code and then call it in your model, and then for the model, I would create a scope, so for example:     `public function scopeLang($query)
    {
     return $query->where('lang', this.language());
    }` Then you would call this in your controller as: `Model::lang()->get();`

Comment: For each model to create the same scope?

Comment: Is it only used with one particular model or multiple models? Is it used with other aspects of your code as well or just models?

Comment: `this.language()` What is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's tons of ways to achieve what you want. Here's an example you could do. Since this function seems to be associated with the request you could add it as a macro in the request:

In one of your service providers do:

```
 Illuminate\Http\Request::macro('getLanguage', function () {
      $languages = ["en", "it"];
      $default = "en";
      return in_array($this->language, $languages) ? $this->language : $default;
 });
```

Then you can use it as part of the request e.g. :

```
 request()->getLanguage(); //using the helper
 Request::getLanguage(); //Using the request facade
 $request->getLanguage(); //If you already have a request object.
```